# Global javascript variable inside document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, scope

Which is the right way of declaring a global javascript variable? The way I'm trying it, doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var intro;

    if ($('.intro_check').is(':checked')) {
        intro = true;
        $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
    };

    $('.intro_check').change(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            intro = false;
            $('.enabled').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            intro = true;
            if($('.intro').exists()) {
                $('.disabled').removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled'); 
            } else {
                $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
            }
        }
    });
});

console.log(intro);
```

Comment: putting the `var` keyword makes it local to the function. either remove it or move the declaration outside of the ready function.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you're declaring a global variable, you might want to use a namespace of some kind.  Just declare the namespace outside, then you can throw whatever you want into it.  Like this...

```
var MyProject = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    MyProject.intro = "";

    MyProject.intro = "something";
});

console.log(MyProject.intro); // "something"
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked for, but cleaner. I'd prefer a closure, though, unless the code is modular, and there's a requirement for cross-module access to the global variable.

Comment: @dbaseman, I like your solution because it would solve some problems and improve some of my code (the code It was prebuild, I just improve it)... but for some reason, when I declare `MyProject.intro = "something";` inside DOM Ready function, I keep getting `undefined` as output in `console.log`

Comment: @w0rldart In the OP code and in the accepted answer, the console log is outside the  $(document.ready(...)). So in most of the cases the the console.log will run when the JS is loaded, and AFTER THAT  the Ready function will be executed when all the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thanks! But why is that I can't console.log() the global variable when I declare it inside $(document).ready ?

Answer (score 37):

declare this

```
var intro;
```

outside of `$(document).ready()` because, `$(document).ready()` will hide your variable from global scope.

**Code**

```
var intro;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.intro_check').is(':checked')) {
        intro = true;
        $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
    };
    $('.intro_check').change(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            intro = false;
            $('.enabled').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            intro = true;
            if($('.intro').exists()) {
                $('.disabled').removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled'); 
            } else {
                $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

#### According to @Zakaria comment

Another way:

```
window.intro = undefined;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.intro_check').is(':checked')) {
        window.intro = true;
        $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
    };
    $('.intro_check').change(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            window.intro = false;
            $('.enabled').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            window.intro = true;
            if($('.intro').exists()) {
                $('.disabled').removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled'); 
            } else {
                $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

### Note

```
console.log(intro);
```

outside of DOM ready function (currently you've) will log `undefined`, but within DOM ready it will give you true/ false.

#### Your outer `console.log` execute before DOM ready execute, because DOM ready execute after all resource appeared to DOM i.e after DOM is prepared, so I think you'll always get absurd result.

---

#### According to comment of @W0rldart

> I need to use it outside of DOM ready function

You can use following approach:

```
var intro = undefined;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.intro_check').is(':checked')) {
        intro = true;
        introCheck();
        $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
    };
    $('.intro_check').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            intro = true;
        } else {
            intro = false;
        }
        introCheck();
    });

});

function introCheck() {
    console.log(intro);
}
```

After change the value of `intro` I called a function that will fire with new value of `intro`.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the question is about declaring a global var inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: @Zakaria I don't care where the variale is declared, I just need it to be global so I can access it from everywhere

Comment: @w0rldart you console.log outside of DOM ready function (currently you've) will log `undefined`, but within DOM ready it will give you true/ false.

Comment: @thecodeparadox I need to use it outside of DOM ready function, because I will use later on in tinymce to know what to activate or not

Comment: @w0rldart Your outer console.log execute before DOM ready execute, because DOM ready execute after all resource appeared to DOM i.e after DOM is prepared, so I think you'll always get absurd result.

Comment: @w0rldart I have update my answer, I think my last part will work for you

Answer (score 14):

JavaScript has **Function-Level** variable scope which means you will have to declare your variable outside `$(document).ready()` function.

Or alternatively to make your variable to have **global** scope, simply dont use `var` keyword before it like shown below. However generally this is considered **bad practice** because it *pollutes* the global scope but it is up to you to decide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   intro = null; // it is in global scope now
```

---

To learn more about it, check out:

- [Explaining JavaScript Scope And Closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

Comment: For some reason, it won't go! When I try the `alert(intro)` or `console.log(intro)` it keeps returning undefined. I tried almost all the solutions proposed in this thread

Comment: @w0rldart: There should be something else wrong. Make sure that you are not re-defining that variable somewhere else and also beware of javascript hoisting: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting. And try your `console.log` command inside the `ready` handler which is where you manipulate the `intro` variable.

Answer (score 7):

Use `window.intro` inside of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @OliverWeiler global variables per say aren't but being explicit about when you're modifying a global variable is pretty good practice I'd say...

Answer (score 3):

You can define the variable inside the document ready function without var to make it a global variable. In javascript any variable declared without var automatically becomes a global variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    intro =  "something";
});
```

although you cant use the variable immediately, but it would be accessible to other functions

Comment: Lovely ! So simple

Answer (score 2):

like this: put `intro` outside your document ready, Good discussion here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-jquery @thecodeparadox is awesomely fast :P anyways!

```
 var intro;

$(document).ready(function() {



    if ($('.intro_check').is(':checked')) {
        intro = true;
        $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
    };

    $('.intro_check').change(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            intro = false;
            $('.enabled').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            intro = true;
            if($('.intro').exists()) {
                $('.disabled').removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled'); 
            } else {
                $('.intro').wrap('<div class="disabled"></div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike another programming languages, any variable declared outside any function automatically becomes global,

```
<script>

//declare global variable
var __foo = '123';

function __test(){
 //__foo is global and visible here
 alert(__foo);
}

//so, it will alert '123'
__test();

</script>
```

You problem is that you declare variable inside `ready()` function, which means that it becomes visible (in scope) ONLY inside `ready()` function, but not outside,

Solution:
So just make it global, i.e declare this one outside `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.intro = "value";` inside the ready function. `"value"` could be `void 0` if you want it to be `undefined`