# Howto use a (global) variable from a module inside jQuery's document ready function?

Tags: javascript, asch-development

According to SO question [Global javascript variable inside document.ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152977/global-javascript-variable-inside-document-ready), I should be able to use global variables inside jQuery's document ready function. How can I do the same when my variable is declared inside a module?

```
<script type="module">
        import settings from './config/settings.js';
        var DAPP_VERSION = settings.version;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var OTHER = 4;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log(OTHER);
        console.log(DAPP_VERSION);
    }); 
</script>
```

The above gives me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DAPP_VERSION is not defined

`config/setting.js` contains:

```
export default {
    version: "1.1",
    rounds: 3,
    cars: 20,   
    lapLenght: "short"
}
```

Comment: Do you test this:  `window.DAPP_VERSION=...`?

Comment: @HassanSadeghi That won't work...and it is advisable to know if suggested solutions work before posting them, and if you tested it yourself, you'd know it didn't

Comment: I am in metro(subway) and I'm typing with mobile phone. I did not have a tool for test it. Sorry.

Comment: Why not just put the `$(document).ready(…)` in a `<script type="module">` where you can `import` that variable directly? The whole point of modules is that you don't need any globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `type="module"` declaration the variables are not attached to the global scope automatically but to the module scope (that is different).

You have to attach them explicitely to window in order to avoid ambiguity and  make them visible across the whole application.

```
window.DAPP_VERSION = settings.version;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R6FNs/572/